# Getting OutOfMemory error while processing huge data into Excel using Apache POI XSSF and SXSSF also

Tags: java, apache-poi

Currently I am using Apache POI API 3.9 version for generating huge excel file but I am getting OutOfmemory error while processing huge data from database. I have some customized templates for Excel with multiple sheets, for 100k records not exported, But I have tried SXSSF API also, but no luck.

```
public void fillSmallTable(XSSFWorkbook wb, XSSFSheet sheet, TableVO conf,
Map<String, String> paramsMap) throws Exception {

String queryFinal = ConfigurationUtils.assignParameters(
conf.getQuery(), paramsMap);
System.out.println("queryFinal >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.. " + queryFinal);
Connection connection = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
int rowNum = conf.getRowStart();
int colNum = conf.getColumnStart();
XSSFCellStyle unlockedCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
unlockedCellStyle.setLocked(false);

XSSFCellStyle hlinkStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
Font hlinkFont = wb.createFont();
hlinkFont.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
hlinkFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
hlinkStyle.setFont(hlinkFont);

try {
connection = dataSource.getConnection();
stmt = connection.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryFinal);
ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
int max = metadata.getColumnCount();
while (rs.next()) {
Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
if (row == null)
row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
colNum = conf.getColumnStart();
for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
Object value = rs.getObject(i);
Cell cell = row.getCell(colNum);
if (cell == null)
cell = row.createCell(colNum);
Excel2007Utils.setPoiCellValue(cell, value);
if (value != null && value.toString().startsWith("http://")) {
cell.setCellStyle(hlinkStyle);
}
String columnName = rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i);
if (editableColumns != null && editableColumns.size() > 0) {
if (editableColumns.contains(columnName)) {
cell.setCellStyle(unlockedCellStyle);
}
}
colNum++;
}
rowNum++;
}
} catch (Exception e) {
throw new Exception("Error executing query " + queryFinal + ": \n"
+ e.getMessage());
} finally {
if (rs != null) {
try {
rs.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
}
}
try {
if (stmt != null)
stmt.close();
} catch (SQLException se2) {
}
try {
if (connection != null)
connection.close();
} catch (SQLException se) {
se.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an old version of Apache POI? And where's your failing SXSSF code? We'll find it very hard to help you with no code to critique...

Comment: I have added my snippet of code please help me to avoid out of memory issue.

Comment: I have huge records from database like 1Lakh while retrieving records from database one by one using rs.next() that time i am getting out of memory issue. 

Please look into above code and let me know the feasibility solution,

I am awaiting your earlier response.

Comment: This appears to be XSSF code, where's the SXSSF one?

Comment: I am passing XSSF work book to SXSSF code and set it as below like
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelTemplate);
 SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook, 100);

Comment: Remaining code as above.